# phpunit: Redefining a mock's behaviour after initial setup

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm building a set of unit tests for a client that uses a HTTP transport layer to communicate with a server.  As it's the client's behaviour I'm interested in I'm mocking the HTTP transport layer instance it uses.  Because setting up mocks in PHPUnit is a pain I've defined a few helper functions in the test class to save me having to configure the mocks for every test.

```
<?php
private function mockTransport()
{
    $mock = $this->getMock(HTTPClient::class);
    $mock->expects($this->any)
        ->method("send")
        ->will($this->returnValue($this->mockHTTPResponse));
    return $mock
}

private function mockHTTPResponse()
{
    $mock = $this->getMock(ResponseInterface::class);
    $mock->expects($this->any)
        ->method("getStatus")
        ->will($this->returnValue(200)); // HTTP 200 OK

    return $mock;
}
```

This is fine for most things, except for when I get to testing cases where the code is something other than 200.  I had intended to manipulate the mocks returned by the above helper methods, but I found that even if I do override the method again, it still returns the same response!

```
    $mock = $this->getMock(ResponseInterface::class);
    $mock->expects($this->any)
        ->method("getStatus")
        ->will($this->returnValue(200)); // HTTP 200 OK
    var_dump ($mock->getStatus()); // 200
    $mock->expects($this->any)
        ->method("getStatus")
        ->will($this->returnValue(400)); // HTTP 400 bad request
    var_dump ($mock->getStatus()); // Still 200!
```

This means that if I need something other than a 200 response I either have to a) build the entire mock structure from scratch (massive pain in the neck that the helper functions were meant to avoid in the first place) or b) pass in a status code argument to mockResponse() (which just feels wrong to me, as tests are supposed to be dumb).

Is it possible to reset the responses a mock will give to a given method call after it's been initially set up?  If so, how?